# how to restore a version of a powerpage powerapps portals

Tags: powerapp, powerapps-portal, dynamics-365, power-pages

how to restore a version of a powerpage powerappsportals.

i did some costom modification using  Script Editor and when i want to restore my page stay blank.

So Please how to restore a version of a powerpage powerappsportals.